# Performance Point Dashboard Designer Select Member Option

Tags: performancepoint

When I try to select members from a dimension into my scorecard (a list of names), nothing appears in the select member box.

I am getting data from a connected SharePoint list the data is set to Dimension.

Any ideas? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that no data is displaying in my data connection list. So there is no actual data for member services to draw from.